# SharePoint - Download large files with just an Access Token?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I've discovered that I can't use SharePoint CSOM to download large files.

[A solution posted online](https://piyushksingh.com/2016/08/15/download-large-files-from-sharepoint-online/) recommends using RPC to download the large file, however authenticates using a Cookie. The cookie is obtained using Username and Password.

In my application, I do not have the users username and password, instead I am using an Access Token.

Is there some way I can get an auth cookie from my Access Token, without needing username/password? Or another way I can download a large file using just my Access Token?

Comment: I would recommend you to use sharepoint app only. Please refer to following steps to get accesstoken https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/in-4-steps-access-sharepoint-online-data-using-postman-tool/